# How to display the NFT of my project on React?

Tags: nft, react, query

I made a project where people can mint my NFT and now I would like to create a webpage on react where the users can see the NFTs that they had minted. Basically, I would like to take the address of the user in input (from the wallet connection) and display his ERC721 tokens filtered with my contract. Can someone tell me a good tutorial to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, welcome to StackExchange. This is a very, very broad question, and it is unlikely that someone can give you a good answer.

Comment: Take a look at [create-eth-app](https://github.com/paulrberg/create-eth-app), it might help you.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at opensea's API. Link: https://docs.opensea.io/reference/getting-assets